# How do I size my Silverlight 2 control to fit the page (The default gives a scrollbar)

Tags: silverlight-2.0

I have a Silverlight 2 control that I wish to fill the browser. I have set no height and width for the outer grid so it resizes. I have set the web page to have a style of height and width 100% and no padding or margin for the html and body tags. The Silverlight object is set to 100% height and width.

When I view the page, IE adds a scrollbar and lets me scroll downwards about four or five pixels, all of which are just white.

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this piece of CSS do the trick?

```
body{
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work IN IE 8, other than in compatibility mode.